# Good books on unsupervised learning

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, books

I am looking for a good book about unsupervised learning that goes beyond the typical k-means and hierarchical clustering algorithms.

Practical implementations in R or Python will be a plus.

Currently I am working in retail, so the typical use cases I am interested are customer segmentation, products segmentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget about lecture notes and slides. I recently saw some very good cluster analysis lecture slides.

Answer (score 2):

There might not be an entire book about unsupervised techniques, given the greater effectiveness of supervised learning techniques. However, there are small books and selected chapters from longer books that could be relevant:

- "[Unsupervised Machine Learning in Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G1HH5T4)" which includes Gaussian Mixture Models
- "[Python Machine Learning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1787125939)" which has a section on Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)
- "[Modeling Techniques in Predictive Analytics with Python and R: A Guide to Data Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133892069)" which has a chapter on Market Basket Analysis
- "[R for Marketing Research and Analytics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319144359)" which covers Confirmatory Factor Analysis and Structural Equation Modeling

Comment: Here are some [detailed cluster analysis lecture notes](https://www.vitavonni.de/blog/201803/2018033001-cluster-analysis-lecture-notes.html).